# Why is search in top bar not working in android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I made an app with `listView` and I want to use search in top bar but it doesn't work.
In this program, I get the data from the firebase.

These are the codes below:

This is `MainActivity` code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int List_APP_LOADER = 0;

    ArrayList<Informatin> listItem;
    ListView listView;
    listAdapter adapter;

    DatabaseReference reference;

    ArrayList<Informatin> mInformation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listItem = new ArrayList<>();
        listView = findViewById(R.id.list);

        LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(LIST_APP_LOADER, null, this);

        mInformation = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new listAdapter(this, mInformation);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_screen, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_item);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                listView.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is `listAdapter` code

```
public class listAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Informatin> implements Filterable {

    List<Informatin> arrayList;

    Context context;
    public listAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Informatin> informatins) {
        super(context, 0, informatins);
        this.context=context;
        arrayList = informatins;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        Informatin currentList = getItem(position);

        TextView nameTextView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView descriptionTextView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        TextView ageTextView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.age);
        ImageView imageView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        String firstName = currentList.getFirstName();
        String lastName = currentList.getLastName();

        String name = firstName + " " + lastName;

        nameTextView.setText(name);
        descriptionTextView.setText(currentList.getDescription());

        ageTextView.setText(currentList.getAge());

        return listItemView;
    }

    List<Informatin> informatins;
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<Informatin> results = new ArrayList<>();
                if (informatins == null)
                    informatins = arrayList;
                if (constraint != null) {
                    if (informatins != null && informatins.size() > 0) {
                        for (final Informatin g : informatins) {
                            if (g.getFirstName().toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(constraint.toString()))
                                results.add(g);
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                arrayList = (ArrayList<Informatin>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

[this is the picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx91O.png)

[this is a screenshot for the problem from the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaaxT.jpg)

Comment: public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                
                adapter.filter(newList);
                return false;
}

Comment: How have you implemented your search filter?share your listadapter code.

Comment: @Danish I have added the codes above

Comment: @MohamedHossam After you do ` adapter.filter(newList);` you need to do `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: @akhilnair I typed this code but nothing happened

Comment: @MohamedHossam Can you please add the code where you are creating your adapter?

Comment: @akhilnair I already wrote the code in onLoadFinished

Comment: @MohamedHossam Is you contructor `listAdapter` just doing what it is shown here? Can you please add the `listAdapter` whole code?

Comment: @akhilnair This is the complete code for the listAdapter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69690898/why-is-search-in-top-bar-not-working-in-android-studio#:~:text=This%20is%20listAdapter,arrayList.addAll(newList)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%7D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your listadapter code:

```
    Context context;
     public listAdapter(Context context, List<Informatin> informatins) {
    super();
    this.context=context;
    arraylist=informatins;

}
    ArrayList<Informatin> informatins;
    public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
            final ArrayList<Informatin> results = new ArrayList<Informatin>();
            if (informatins == null)
                informatins = arraylist;
            if (constraint != null) {
                if (informatins != null && informatins.size() > 0) {
                    for (final Information g : informatins) {
                        if (g.getName().toLowerCase()
                                .contains(constraint.toString()))
                            results.add(g);
                    }
                }
                oReturn.values = results;
            }
            return oReturn;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            arraylist = (ArrayList<Informatin>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

Add this in your onquerytextchaged:

```
       searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
           adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);//replace adapter with listview name which in your case is listview as informed by you in comment
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
```

Modified MainActivity onCreate() code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listItem = new ArrayList<>();
    listView = findViewById(R.id.list);

    LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(LIST_APP_LOADER, null, this);

    mInformation = new ArrayList<>();

    adapter = new listAdapter(this, mInformation);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true)//add this line
}
```

Comment: What is the employeeArrayList

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Comment: I mean this line `informatins = employeeArrayList;`

Comment: sorry it was mistake from my side.Check now

Comment: I tried it and nothing happened

Comment: Upload tried code now.

Comment: But how `informatin``(List)` = `arrayList`

Comment: we need to copy the real list to other arraylist to make sure that the real list is being preserved during search process and the result is being showed using the copied list.

Comment: The app is also not working
Please take a look at the codes I will put the new codes

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69690898/why-is-search-in-top-bar-not-working-in-android-studio#:~:text=0,results.values%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20notifyDataSetChanged()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I use firebase in that list

Comment: Is your listview name adapter??

Comment: No its name is listView

Comment: Replace adapter.getfilter.filter(newText)  with listview.getfilter.filter(newText)

Comment: But when I write this code, the word getFilter is colored red

Comment: Upload your whole code i will provide you with the working solution.

Comment: I have updated the codes

Comment: check my updated answer at MainActivity onCreate().

Comment: But in this code(listview.getFilter().filter(newText);), the word getFilter is colored red

Comment: What error is it showing on hovering cursor over it?Have a look at onquerytextchange,I have made some changes.

Comment: When I tried the changes, the words I typed into the search appeared at the bottom of the screen highlighted

Comment: Cant get ur words?if u dont mind do upload screenshot of ur problem

Comment: When I hover over `getFilter` with the cursor it shows me `Rename reference`

Comment: I have changed that part of code.Have a relook at that line in my answer.

Comment: When I tried the changes `listView.setFilterText(newText);`,  the words that i typed into the search appeared at the bottom of the screen with highlight

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the problem from the device

Comment: Got your problem.Actually the code highlights the text of the listview but you want a seperate list of listview that contains the search keyword so you have to do search on your adapter.Apply filter on your adapter only like you applied previously.Updated my code again check it out at onqueryTextChanged.

Comment: Just saw your problem do what i have mentioned in above comment.

Comment: I applied it but the problem wasn't solved

Comment: Whats the new problem?

Comment: Follow this tutorial:https://youtu.be/dQemVwgAL9c

Comment: Thank you for your patience, the problem is solved

Comment: Upload the solution.

Comment: There is no problem with your code but the problem is that in the` listAdapter `file I was using this code `public class listAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Informatin> implements Filterable {`
But the correct solution is this code:` public class listAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {`

Comment: I didnt notice that.JazakAllahKhair!Thanks alot for sharing ur solution.